# Confusion Adjusting/Using the Rotation Vector of Bones in Drivers

Tags: bones, drivers

I am currently using bone drivers to basically rig a model I created using geometry nodes. While I have been able to get around issues when the local orientation of a bone differs from the object, I have met my match with the last drivers I have to create.

Currently I have two bones that head downward. From my understanding, this means that the local orientation of the bones are rotated 90° around the x axis. Using this, I've managed to be able to use the local position of the bones simply by taking the (x, y, z) and converting to (x, z, -y). This has also proven true (with the exception of the -y) for using the local scale of the bones. However, I'm having issues when extending this property to rotation.

[image: Two bones point downwards with the local bone axis being visible where Y heading down, X towards the camera, and Z perpendicular]

When taking the local rotation of the bones and converting (x, y, z) to (x, z, -y), I run into an issue when I rotate in both the y and z directions beyond 0°/90°/180°/270°/(and so on)(but not when rotation in just xy or xz directions). Below I created drivers that align an axis object (blue for z, green for y, and red for x) using the conversion above. When the receiving results as expected, the z axis points the opposite direction of the bone, however it drifts from this orientation when rotating around both the y and z axis. The "working" example has the bone set to (0°, 50°, 0°) with the drivers reading (0°, 0°, -50°). The "issue" example has the bone set to (0°, 50°, -45°) with the drivers reading (0°, -45°, -50°).

[image: The bone is rotated (0°, 50°, 0°) for the bone's local axis with the drivers rotating the axis object (0°, 0°, -50°). The bone points the opposite direction of the blue axis representing the object z axis.]
[image: The bone is rotated (0°, 50°, -45°) for the bone's local axis with the drivers rotating the axis object (0°, -45°, -50°). The bone points downward meanwhile the blue axis representing the object z axis points up and to the right.]

At other times I get unexpected results outputs between the bone and the driver. For one image, the bone is locally rotated (0°, 90°, 45°) which the driver reads as (-45°, 0°, -90°) when it should've been converted to (0°, 45°, -90°). Changing the bone rotation to (0°, 90.1°, 45°) does properly convert to (0°, 45°, -90.1°), though the aforementioned issue of the bone no longer lining up with the mesh appears again. I suspect this is a symptom of the same issue.

[image: The bone is rotated (0°, 90°, 45°) for the bone's local axis with the drivers rotating the axis object (-45°, 0°, -90°). The bone points the opposite direction of the blue axis representing the object z axis.]
[image: The bone is rotated (0°, 90.1°, 45°) for the bone's local axis with the drivers rotating the axis object (0°, 45°, -90.1°). The bone points down to the left meanwhile the blue axis representing the object z axis points straight up.]

When compared to how the conversion (x, y, z) to (x, z, -y) works without flaw for using the bone's local position to control an object's location through drivers, I'm left wondering if bones handle local rotation differently that doesn't let the simple rotation matrix to work.

Comment: A possible solution from additional testing may be setting the bone to use XZY Euler when setting rotation instead of keeping the bones on Quaternion or XYZ Euler. I am not sure if there is a problem keeping the drivers on Auto.

Hopefully someone can confirm this for me or provide an explanation for why this is the case.